# Bulk action from the gridview list, yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a gridview list of customers with a checkbox column.
I would like to have a button that will send all my checked customers to a form action, that will receive the customers email address, and enable me to send a bulk email.
I have no idea how to send the data of the checked customers, or even only their emails, from the gridview list to the email action, and how to receive it in there.
How do I catch the checked data to send it with a link?
Thanks.

Comment: May help you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633634/yii2-gridview-checkbox-apply-selected-class)

Comment: you can use **pjex**

Comment: And how do i catch the checked rows with pjax?